# How to pass double quotes in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex, rest

I have to make an ajax call to node.js server from jquery and the data  contains some metacharacter like * and makes a regex based search. The data looks like this:

```
var obj = {"field": "*\"comment*" };
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/getData/'+JSON.stringify(obj),
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    timeout: 400000,
    error: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

But I end up seeing an error (may be because the GET request has double quotes(") in it). How do I make it happen even with  quotes in it.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent()` the string before sending.

Comment: @Jai Thanks, you made my life easier :)